# Botão para carregar página

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma página com conteúdo adulto e gostaria de colocar dois botões, um para entrar e outro para sair. Como poderia fazer isso em JavaScript?

A tela toda ficaria escura, com um botão que liberaria o conteúdo, e o outro que redirecionaria o utilizador para a página inicial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mostrar/Ocultar bloco em JavaScript

Se o conteúdo estiver dentro de um `div`, então...

Usaremos uma folha de estilo CSS para definir a visibilidade da `div`

```
<style>
#oculto{
    display: none;  
}
</style>
```

O bloco que usaremos para ocultar

```
 <div id="oculto">
     Seu conteúdo a ser ocultado
 </div>
```

O botão para mostrar/ocultar a div

```
<button onclick="mostrar();">Botão</button>
```

Script em javascript que ocultará/mostrará a div

```
  <script>
    var visivel = false;

    function mostrar(){
    var objDiv = document.getElementById('oculto');     
       if (visivel == false){
          objDiv.style.display = "block"; 
          visivel = true;             
       }else{
          objDiv.style.display = "none";
          visivel = false;         
    }
    }
    </script>
```

```html
    <style>
    #oculto{
     display: none; 
    }
    </style>

   

     <div id="oculto">
         Conteúdo
        </div>


    <button onclick="mostrar();">Mostar/ocultar</button>

  

      <script>
        var visivel = false;
        
        function mostrar(){
        var objDiv = document.getElementById('oculto');     
           if (visivel == false){
              objDiv.style.display = "block"; 
              visivel = true;             
           }else{
              objDiv.style.display = "none";
              visivel = false;         
        }
        }
        </script>
```

O que este script faz é o seguinte:

1. Declara uma variável 'visível' e atribui de antemão o valor 'false'.
2. Declara a variável 'objDiv' que é o elemento que ocultaremos.
3. Faz uma condição para que se visível for falso, deverá mostrar o 'objDiv' e reatribui um valor a variável, neste caso, um valor contrário. E caso visível for verdadeiro, ele não mostra o 'objDiv' e também reatribui um valor contrário ao atual à variável.

No seu caso, como quer escurecer a tela e coisas do tipo, você deve estilizar com CSS.

Leia mais sobre CSS [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp)
Leia mais sobre condicionais [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp)

Comment: Uma outra duvida. Como poderia fazer com dois botões no meio da tela, e ao entrar no conteúdo, o botão sumisse. No caso a tela estaria escura "preta" com os botões no meio.